# Issue with custom service systemd when start Apache Gobblin

Tags: systemd, gobblin

Running `/opt/gobblin/bin/gobblin-standalone.sh start` directly everything works, the output in logs are fine.

Running it through a systemd service, not works. Nothing are outputting in logs.

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo systemctl start gobblin
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo systemctl status gobblin
● gobblin.service - Gobblin Data Ingestion Framework
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/gobblin.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Sun 2019-01-20 16:44:23 UTC; 693ms ago
     Docs: https://gobblin.readthedocs.io
  Process: 9673 ExecStop=/opt/gobblin/bin/gobblin-standalone.sh stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 9671 ExecStart=/opt/gobblin/bin/gobblin-standalone.sh start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 9671 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 20 16:44:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: gobblin.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 20 16:44:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit gobblin.service entered failed state.
Jan 20 16:44:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: gobblin.service failed.
Jan 20 16:44:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: gobblin.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 20 16:44:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Gobblin Data Ingestion Framework.
Jan 20 16:44:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for gobblin.service
Jan 20 16:44:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Gobblin Data Ingestion Framework.
Jan 20 16:44:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit gobblin.service entered failed state.
Jan 20 16:44:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: gobblin.service failed.
```

The code of `/usr/lib/systemd/system/gobblin.service` below:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gobblin Data Ingestion Framework
Documentation=https://gobblin.readthedocs.io
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=gobblin
Group=gobblin
WorkingDirectory=/opt/gobblin
ExecStart=/opt/gobblin/bin/gobblin-standalone.sh start
ExecStop=/opt/gobblin/bin/gobblin-standalone.sh stop
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Perhaps the way are file [gobblin-standalone.sh](https://github.com/apache/incubator-gobblin/blob/master/bin/gobblin-standalone.sh) is builded, not possibility that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is with `Type=oneshot`, `RemainAfterExit=true` and set the environments:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gobblin Data Ingestion Framework
Documentation=https://gobblin.readthedocs.io
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=gobblin
Group=gobblin
WorkingDirectory=/opt/gobblin
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.191.b12-1.el7_6.x86_64/jre
Environment=GOBBLIN_FWDIR=/opt/gobblin
Environment=GOBBLIN_JOB_CONFIG_DIR=/etc/gobblin
Environment=GOBBLIN_WORK_DIR=/var/lib/gobblin
Environment=GOBBLIN_LOG_DIR=/var/log/gobblin
ExecStart=/opt/gobblin/bin/gobblin-standalone.sh start
ExecStop=/opt/gobblin/bin/gobblin-standalone.sh stop
RemainAfterExit=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```